# Help needed in identifying a string

Tags: encoding, steganography, ctf

I need help in identifying the following string in order to decode it to a piece of meaningful information.

h_t_s_/_g_s_._k_l_b_c_m_4_9_a_k_6_f_8_4_8_e_e_r_9_3_9_f_

Comment: Please provide some context. This could be anything

Comment: maybe a URL? https:/

Comment: If this is a CTF, then it will be simple, or there will be clues. It seems obviously to be a URL. h`t`t`p`s`/`/`:` ....

Comment: It looks like every other character of a URL. Filling in a few obvious gaps: `https://g_s_.skylab.com/4_9_a_k_6_f_8_4_8_e_e_r_9_3_9_f_`. If, as schroeder asks, this is a CTF, there's presumably the other half somewhere else... (`skylab` guessed because Google shows some connection between that name and CTFs).